# Cannot set/enable HPA on SSD using hdparm (SG_IO: bad/missing data)

Tags: linux, ssd, sata, ahci, hdparm

I am trying to set up a HPA on a new 2TB Patriot P210 SATA SSD:

```
$ sudo hdparm -Np3600000000 --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 setting max visible sectors to 3600000000 (permanent)
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 a0 ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 max sectors  = 4000797360/4000797360, HPA is disabled
```

This was after I made sure the drive was not frozen. I tried it in Gparted Live (1.4.06) [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyqMK.jpg) /// [and here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcQas.jpg), SSD connected directly to the SATA port. I also tried afterwards using an SATA-to-USB enclosure, but no luck either. I cannot seem to figure out where the problem is or if it is simply the drive itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cheap consumer drives do not support lot of features. And this one of these.

Of cause for drives supporting HPA, after setting it, you need to do complete power cycle: power off, wait a minute until complete discharge, and power on again. Then drive reports max sectors as set in HPA.

On these cheap drives I found out that even temperature sensors are missing, and drives like SPS A55 and InnovationIT SSD always report constant fake temperature of 40C.

From my own experience, Patriot P210 SSD drives are of terrible quality, and I was unable to resolve issues with warranty.

These drives constantly freezes, all OS get stuck and only resolution is complete power cycle.

Unlucky for me, I bought bunch of them during discount sale, and at the end had to give up at half price.

They suit to hold movies for reading, but even fill write process will take ages.